# Git hooks "real life" examples

Tags: git

I've been using git more and more, and I want to use it's full potential. So I've been started reading about git hooks, but I keep running into the same examples.

So here is my question/request: Can you guys give me some examples of what are you using git hooks for in your projects?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think the most common example I have on my mind is the running of the test suite. I for one have a git `pre-push` hook which runs my test suite so that you won't push code which is broken.

Comment: So that means you push your commits, and if the test fails the push wont happen?

Comment: The push fails. Technically what happens, you assign a script or a shell command which will run on a specific git hook. In linux/unix (at least) any process has an exit code. If the process/script was executed succsefully it will exit it a code **0**. This will continue the process chain and execute the git hook. However if the script exists with an error code, the command will fail and the git hook won't execute.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

I used to run my personal CI mini-server using [Sismo](http://sismo.sensiolabs.org) by setting a Git `post-commit` hook to run Sismo after each commit.

Read [this article](http://axiac.ro/blog/atlassian-sourcetree-and-git-hooks/) about how I configured it and made it work with Atlassian SourceTree. It was running well from the command line but for some reason, SourceTree was waiting for the script to complete instead of letting it to run in the background.

Comment: Thanks mate! Very useful! :)